# Calculate average score with missing values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel-sheet with student grades, ranging from 0 to 5.
If a student didn't submit a solution for the test he/she gets a score of 'NA'.

My sheet looks like the following:

| student | test 1 | test 2 | test 3 | test 4 | test 5 | average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| student 1 | 3 | 2 | NA | 4 | 2 |  |
| student 2 | 2,5 | NA | 3,5 | 3 | 2,5 |  |
| student 3 | 3,5 | 4 | NA | NA | 4 |  |

My question is: how can I replace the 'NA' by a score of 0 but **only in the formula** for calculating the average (so **not** the cell-contents)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use AVERAGE function and you should not get an error. Are you getting an error? What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Should N/A count towards the average? But it sounds like the IFNA() function will do what you’re after

Comment: @SQLTemp Yes, N/A counts as 0

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: I use Office 2019.
I dont recieve an error, but the result is incorrect

Comment: @SQLTemp How can I combine the IFNA() and AVERAGE() functions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AVERAGEA function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averagea-function-f5f84098-d453-4f4c-bbba-3d2c66356091) to include strings:

For example:

```
=AVERAGEA(B2:F2)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm!